# Can I use Typescript classes in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Using a Typescript class looking something like this:

```
class MainCtrl {

    constructor() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.variable = "Text";
    }
}

app.controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);
```

Compiles to

```
var MainCtrl = (function () {
    function MainCtrl() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.variable = "Text";
    }
    return MainCtrl;
})();
app.controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);
```

And since I have not quite grasped IIFE's yet, I cant read from this if the `MainCtrl`object is a function I can shove into the controller definition like this or not. And how would I handle injections?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `export` you `MainCtrl` class so your class definition should look like

```
export class MainCtrl {
   ...
}
```

If you're referring to how you can `$inject` in your typescript code then you can use this syntax in your `MainCtrl` class:

```
public static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$location',
        'MyCustmSvc'
];
```

And in you TS constructor:

```
constructor(
        private $scope: IAppNameScope,
        private $location: ng.ILocationService,
        private IMyCustomSvc) {

   var vm = this;
   vm.variable = "Text";
}
```

Any parameter with an `I` before it requires you to define a typescript `interface` for it.

Your compiled JS should now look something like this:

```
var MainCtrl = (function () {
    function MainCtrl($scope, $location, MyCustomSvc) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.variable = "Text";
    }
    return MainCtrl;

 MainCtrl.$inject = [
       '$scope',
       '$location',
       'MyCustomSvc'
 ];
return MainCtrl;
})();
app.controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run an initialize step that converts the TS class into a thing you can use. We do something similar for React components- React uses `React.createClass` to create factories rather than using the classes directly, so we iterate over all of our classes that derive from a specific TS base, and then replace those values with the result of `React.createClass`.

TS classes are ultimately just variables that you can wrap as you please into another form. Also, if you reflect on some "modules", you can remove that hideous call to `App.controller` and do that as an init step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use TypeScript classes with Angular.

With TypeScript you do not need to use `var vm = this` inside your controller. Just use `controllerAs 'vm'` instead.

Your example above becomes:

```
export class MainCtrl {

    variable = "text";

}
app.controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);
```

So now you can access this in your views like:

{{vm.variable}}

To inject into your controller you will use the standard Angular `$inject` annotation. This works nicely with TypeScript.

```
export class MainCtrl {

    static $inject = ['$http'];
    constructor(private $http) {}

    submit(form: YourForm) {
        this.$http.post('/api/form', form);
    }
}
```

Now from the view you can submit a form with `vm.submit()`. `$http` is injected and accessable from any internal method in the controller.

Notice I use `export`. This allows you to use the Class type definition within your unit tests.

Not only should `Controllers` be created as classes. `Services` should as well. The only difference is Angular will instantiate services as singletons, so there will only be one instance -- where `Controllers` can be instantiated with many instances.